# bulk create using ListSerializer of Django Rest Framework

Tags: django

Iam trying to bulk create rows for a certain table using Django Rest Framework. I see in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-multiple-create) that DRF supports it.

views.py

```
class UserProfileFeedViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Handles creating, reading and updating profile feed items."""

    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    queryset = models.ProfileFeedItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProfileFeedItemSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    permission_classes = (permissions.PostOwnStatus, IsAuthenticated)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """Sets the user profile to the logged in user."""

        serializer.save(user_profile=self.request.user)
```

serializers.py

```
class ProfileFeedItemListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
   def create(self,validated_data):
       feed_list = [ProfileFeedItem(**item) for item in validated_data]
       return ProfileFeedItem.objects.bulk_create(feed_list)

class ProfileFeedItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """A serializer for profile feed items."""

    class Meta:
        model = models.ProfileFeedItem
        list_serializer_class = ProfileFeedItemListSerializer
        fields = ('id', 'user_profile', 'status_text', 'created_on')
        extra_kwargs = {'user_profile': {'read_only': True}}
```

When i try posting using admin form i always get this error. Can you please help me identify what am i doing wrong here ?

> TypeError at /api/feed/ 'ProfileFeedItemListSerializer' object is not
>   callable Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/feed/ Django Version: 1.11 Exception
>   Type: TypeError Exception Value:   'ProfileFeedItemListSerializer'
>   object is not callable Exception
>   Location: /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/profiles_api/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py
>   in get_serializer, line 111 Python
>   Executable:   /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/profiles_api/bin/python Python
>   Version:  3.5.2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try it:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    many = isinstance(request.data, list)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=many)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, headers=headers)

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    if type(serializer.validated_data) == list:
         for item in serializer.validated_data:
              item.update({'user_profile': self.request.user})
    else:
        serializer.validated_data.update({'user_profile': self.request.user})
    serializer.save()
```

unfortunately now I can't check the solution, but maybe it will give right way

Comment: Iam able to post single dictionary datasets with this but posting list of dictionaries continues to throw 

**AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'**

Comment: when i pass a list of dataset the code flow does not even reach perform_create. It always expects the data to be passed as a dictionary. 

There must be a way to tell DRF that the incoming data is a list of dictionaries and not a single dictionary.

Comment: added the `create` method

Comment: Awesome...that created the multiple rows for passed dataset. But the **AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'** trace still shows up in console..How do i suppress it ?

Comment: The AttributeError occurs only while i post from Django Admin form. It does not occur while posting via postman.

Comment: i never use django admin, you need look on the request data, possible it can work without any changes, you have not standard issue

Comment: @BearBrown will it be a insert_all or insert one by one when many = true param is provided?

Comment: @JissRaphel i find onky the code https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L940 so i think the drf create objects one by one

Comment: @BearBrown what if I need a view to List and Update objects in bulk instead of creating?

Answer (score 1):

Serializer_class should be class, not class instance. Try to change this

```
serializer_class = serializers.ProfileFeedItemSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

to this:

```
serializers.ProfileFeedItemSerializer
```

Comment: I changed that. Iam trying to post the following dataset:

[{
    "status_text": "Hello"
},{
    "status_text": "World"
}
]

Now when i submit the form i see following error in console:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: @Prasanna can you add full error text to the question?

Comment: @Prasanna try to add `serializer = self.get_serializer(data=self.request.data, many=True)` before `serializer.save(user_profile=self.request.user)` line in `UserProfileFeedViewSet`

Comment: Added the get_serializer but still the same error as full trace above...

Comment: @Prasanna I changed my comment, did you try it?

Comment: Yes i did try that too but still same error after restarting server.